# infinite scrolling in both ways within div

Tags: infinite-loop, infinite-scroll

i'm making a website with 3 div columns that have overflow: scroll. (see screensho there: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13769038/Schermafbeelding%202015-05-04%20om%2017.37.40kopie.jpg)

I want to make the image scrolling divs infinite as in: they should loop. The end of the div should be connected with the beginning of the div seamless.

I found this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2L23c/

this is exactly what i want to do, but it wont work in my html. I think it is using the body to scroll and not a individual div, and since my body is height: 100% it will not scroll properly.

any way to make this work? here's the JS from the fiddle:

```
        (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var html = $(".what").html();
        var what = '<div class="what">'+html+'</div>';
        $(window).scrollTop(1);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
                $(".what").last().after(what);
                if ($(".what").length > 2) {
                    $(".what").last().prev().remove();
                    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - $(".what").first().height());
                }
            }
            else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
                $(".what").first().before(what);
                $(window).scrollTop($(".what").first().height());
                if ($(".what").length > 2) {
                    $(".what").last().remove();
                }
            }    
        });
    }); 
})( jQuery );
```

html

```
 <div class="what">
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_27Ai9FzK4gE/SQzMV9lH2jI/AAAAAAAAAYU/zY9yp_HpCx8/s400/brick_wall.jpg"/>  
    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5Olo8-EgrZI/TZBqclcfPqI/AAAAAAAAC5c/920EyWecwiU/s640/background_brick_wall.jpg"/>

    <img src="http://www.macrobusiness.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Brick-Wall-With-Lights-stock4221-large.png"/>
    <img src="http://parktownprawn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/brick-stone-wall-grey.jpg"/>
```

CSS

```
div.what{
width:400px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
IMG{
max-width:400px;
}
```

Mathieu

Comment: hi mathieu , can you add your css + html related code?

Comment: did that — it is all in the JSfiddle though. but it has not the div required to scroll in. it scrolls in its body now i think.. and thats what i want to change

Comment: is this your own jsfiddle or the one you found? reason im asking is so that i can see the div names that you want to use and change to.

Comment: it's one i found. i was thinking of using the 'what' class as an extra class on my divs.

Comment: up to you, i just want to add your html and css divs in order to see how i can modify the jsfiddle to your situation

Comment: i'll make a JSfiddle with my situation. give me a few minutes!

Comment: right here: http://jsfiddle.net/2L23c/47/

it's actually 3 columns that should infinite scroll up & down like the example jsfiddle.

Comment: @goldeneye any luck?

Comment: Sorry mathieu, got called out yesterday, ill give it a go here now :)

Comment: @goldeneye no problem! just let me know something if something works out :)

Comment: @goldeneye: did you find any solution for this problem? I dont want to be a nag, but you would save me great amounts of time with this ;)

Comment: Sorry, there seems to be more to it than I expected ha I thought it would be an easy fix but if I change one to scroll infinite the rest break